# the best way of release UIView when pop up the view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, background, dealloc

My project have a `UINavigationController`,the root view is a `UITableView`(A) which list all albums in my iPhone, when user touch the album, the `UINavigationController` will push another costumed `UITableView`(B) which used to show the photos of the album like a grid view, every photo is a subclass of `UIView`. The photo will be initialised at the `viewDidLoad`(B). If the photos number is very huge, such as 1000+, table view B's display will be delayed obviously. 
The worst thing is when `UINavigationController` pop up B, the dealloc will be called which I used for release the `UIView`(1000+), I can not release these `UIViews` at backend, so I have to do this in main thread, but in this way the main thread will be locked for a few seconds.

Here're my questions:
1. What is the best way of loading the photos to decrease the delay?
2. What's the correct way of releasing the huge number of `UIView`? (By the way, I used the MRC)

Comment: Why are you using MRC in this day and age? You should not load all the images at once, you should only load the images for the cells that the UITableView wants to display

Comment: I really should use ARC instead of MRC, but I just want to know how to solve this problem, especially the second questions, if release UIView cost long time , The UI will be blocked ?

Comment: She the rest of my comment